# Update multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I want to update multiple product_variant of one product. At same time I also update product name.
What I am updating is:

```
Product-> name
Product_variant(can be multiple)->name & price
```

Code I tried:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->name = $request->product_name;
$product->update();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->variant_name); $i++) {
        $variant = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get();
       $variant->variant_name = $request->variant_name[$i];
       $variant->variant_price = $request->variant_price[$i];
       $variant->update();
 }
```

In view:

```
  <form action="{{ route('product.update',$product->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label>{{ __('Product Name') }}</label>
    <input id="product_name" type="text" name="product_name" value="{{ $product->name }}" required autofocus>
    @foreach($product->product_variant as $variant)
            <label>{{ __('Variant') }}</label>
             <input id="product_name" type="text" name="variant_name[]" value=" 
                {{ $variant->variant_name }}" required autofocus>
              <input id="product_name" type="text" name="variant_price[]" value=" 
                {{ $variant->variant_price }}" required autofocus>
   @endforeach
      <button type="submit" class="rounded btn btn-primary">
              {{ __('Update') }}
       </button>                
  </form>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem or any error occur?

Comment: Getting this error,
 BadMethodCallException {#280 ▼
  #message: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist."

Comment: problem is appear when i update product_variants.

Comment: And you have the same name for input variants for name and price. Please change it

Comment: still getting error

Comment: Please share your database product and variants table. I think the problem is in the loop

Comment: Because the product has many variants and when you get the variants is in the for loop, the $variants variable fetches the collections

Comment: yes, i also think that problem in loop but i am not passing id of variants.

Comment: Hey share your database tables I think I can solve your problem

Comment: check op i edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try** this code:

```
$details = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get();

foreach ($details as $key => $detail) {
   $detail->variant_name = $request->get('variant_name')[$key];
   $detail->variant_price = $request->get('variant_price')[$key];
   $detail->save();
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.

**Note:-** Assuming that the equal number of product variants rows and the input variant rows against specific id.

But I advise you to add a unique `variant label` column in the `Product Variants` table, for updating the values against the label of variants.

Comment: perfect. Thank you. Same what i am trying right now. Thank again. Would you please explain.I am getting what you are doing but I want to understand precisely

Comment: Welcome bro... Simply I am first getting the collections against product_id and foreach collections I am getting the value from input variant and update it..... It is done in a single loop because the table rows and the input rows has the equal number.

Comment: what meaning of this **But I advise you to add a unique variant label column in the Product Variants table, for updating the values against the label of variants.**

Comment: It means that in the above code you have to simply update data using loop but when if unique column added in the product variants table then you can update the data against that column precisely. It's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, when you're getting $variants from database, you get a collection of your ProductVariant (one to many relationship), and this is the why you get the error "Method Collection::update does not exist.". Laravel get() returns a collection of ProductVariant.

It looks you want to update all of the product_variants belonging to one product with same name and price. So it's better you get the product_variants outside of the loop and then do your loop through the collection you get.

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->name = $request->product_name;
$product->update();
$variants = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get(); // This return a collection of ProductVariant
foreach ($variants as $variant) {

    $variant->variant_name = $request->variant_name;
    $variant->variant_price = $request->variant_price;
    $variant->update();
}
```

But, if you need to update the variants of one product with different names and prices that you get from your request, first you need to change the name attribute of the text inputs in your html:

```
<input id="product_name" type="text" name="variant_name_{{$variant->id}}" value=" {{ $variant->variant_name }}" required autofocus>

<input id="product_name" type="text" name="variant_price_{{$variant->id}}" value=" {{ $variant->variant_price }}" required autofocus>
```

Then in your code:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->name = $request->product_name;
$product->update();
$variants = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get(); // This return a collection of ProductVariant
foreach ($variants as $variant) {

    $nameIdentifier = "variant_name_" . $variant->id;
    $priceIdentifier = "variant_price_" . $variant->id;
    $variant->variant_name = $request->$nameIdentifier;
    $variant->variant_price = $request->$priceIdentifier;
    $variant->update();
}
```

Also, since you want a set of operations in your request, I prefer to go with database transaction. In that case, if anything goes wrong during the operations you could safely rollback.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank but still getting error QueryException {#276 ▼
  #sql: "update `product_variants` set `variant_name` = ?, `variant_price` = ?, `updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?"
  #bindings: array:4 [▼
    0 => array:18 [▶]
    1 => array:18 [▶]
    2 => "2019-02-22 11:40:03"
    3 => 1
  ]
  #message: "Array to string conversion (SQL: update `product_variants` set `variant_name` = Catch up, `variant_price` = 12, `updated_at` = 2019-02-22 11:40:03 where `id` = 1) "

Comment: Do you update each `product_variant` with a different name and price?

Comment: Yeah, it's because your request returns an array. Sorry, I was thinking you want to update all variants with the same name, price. I'll update my answer now

Comment: @Namoshek, just updated my answer by adding a unique name for each product_variant in the html, so you could update each product_variant with it's specific name comes from the html form. Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

**You need to use first() instead of get()**

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
$product->name = $request->product_name;
$product->update();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->variant_name); $i++) {
       $variant = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->first();
       $variant->variant_name = $request->variant_name[$i];
       $variant->variant_price = $request->variant_price[$i];
       $variant->save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are calling collection in by using get() method on eloquent which returns array of data which is known as collection and update() function can be called on single object not on array of objects.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->variant_name); $i++) {
    $variant = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get(); //here you are doing mistake change get() to first() then it should work
   $variant->variant_name = $request->variant_name[$i];
   $variant->variant_price = $request->variant_price[$i];
   $variant->update(); // change update function to save(); since update function requires array of data which you want to send to database in your case you are calling update function without sending any data.
```

}

If you want to get collection and update each record then loop that collection and do your logic there like shown below.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->variant_name); $i++) {
    $variant_collection = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get(); // it will return collection now you have to loop over to change each record.
    foreach($variant_collection as $variant_single_record){
       $variant_single_record->variant_name = $request->variant_name[$i];
       $variant_single_record->variant_price = $request->variant_price[$i];
       $variant_single_record->save();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$details = ProductVariant::where('product_id',$id)->get();

if ($details->count() > 0) {
  foreach ($details as $key => $detail) {
      $detail->variant_name = $request->get('variant_name')[$key];
      $detail->variant_price = $request->get('variant_price')[$key];
      $detail->save();
  }
}
```